# How to minimize the memory used at spring MapJobExecutionDao

Tags: java, spring, memory, spring-batch

I took a heapdump from my app and I can see 3 objects that are consuming a lot memory

`org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao`: 124MB

`org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao`: 120MB

`org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapExecutionContextDao`: 92MB

What can I do to minimize the use of the memory of these objects?

Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use them :)  Those are essentially `HashMap`s that will grow as long as your java process is running.  Per the javadoc for the `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` the Map based job repository isn't intended for production use.

Comment: so... what do I use? Do you think if I use spring-ehCache it get better?

Comment: I can see a clear method but I do not know how to call it... http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/MapJobExecutionDao.html#clear--

Comment: how about to use Quartz?

Comment: Those classes have nothing to do with scheduling/orchestration.  Use HSQLDB configured in memory and configure a task to run delete scripts from it periodically...